# Call help file in .net window application

Tags: chm

We want to know how to show related topic of help file  when user click F1 on specific interface.

Thanks
H N Mishra

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows forms, have a look at a help provider.

Dropping one on your form will give you a ? button in the corner which you can then wire up to each control.  You can even hyperlink that into a CHM file, along with any other part that you wish to do.

Answer (score 1):

You may use HelpProvider & HelpNavigator controls. Calling help will look something like this

```
private void F1pressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Help.ShowHelp(this, helpProvider.HelpNamespace, HelpNavigator.Topic, "screen_8383.htm");
}
```